# Trouble creating instances with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, interface, parent-child, instance-variables

I am having trouble utilizing my instance data to create corresponding array that is based on the slot index. In this case "Solar" or "Climate" will determine which array to create.
I NEED help with main and createWarehouses methods ONLY.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WarehouseTest
{



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SolarWarehouse sw1 = new SolarWarehouse ( "2200", "10", "5", "5", "First Street", "Dallas", "Texas", "76000", "Solar", "25");

        ClimateControlledWarehouse ccw1  = new ClimateControlled Warehouse ( "5550", "12.75", "2", "3", "Mitchell Drive", "Arlington", "Texas", "76019", "Climate", "80.5");
        ClimateControlledWarehouse ccw2  = new ClimateControlled Warehouse ("12000", "17.50", "6", "7", "Jones Blvd", "Burleson", "Texas", "76120", "Climate", "77.3");
        SolarWarehouse sw2 = new SolarWarehouse ("7235", "22.35", "54", "80", "Smith Circle", "Keller", "Texas", "75020", "Solar", "6");


        Warehouse wArray[] = new Warehouse[4];

        wArray[0] = sw1;
        wArray[1] = ccw1;
        wArray[2] = ccw2;
        wArray[3] = sw2;

        wArray = createWarehouses(dataArray);



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, purchaseItems(wArray));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printWarehouses(wArray));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printWarehouseCharge(wArray));

    } 


    public static Warehouse[] createWarehouses( String a[][])
    {
        Warehouse w[] = new Warehouse[a.length];

        for( int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {


            if(a[i][8].equals("Solar"))


                    w[i] = new SolarWarehouse(Double.parseInt(a[i][0]), 
                        Double.parseDouble(a[i][1], 
                        Integer.parseInt(a[i][2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(a[i][3]),
                        new Address(a[i][4]), 
                        (a[i][5]), 
                        (a[i][6]),
                        (Integer.parseInt(a[i][7]),
                        (a[i][8]), Integer.parseInt(a[i][9])));
            else
                    w[i] = new ClimateControlledWarehouse(Double.parseInt(a[i][0]), 
                        Double.parseDouble(a[i][1], 
                        Integer.parseInt(a[i][2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(a[i][3]),
                        new Address(a[i][4]), 
                        (a[i][5]), 
                        (a[i][6]),
                        (Integer.parseInt(a[i][7]),
                        (a[i][8]), Integer.parseInt(a[i][9]))); 

        }

        return w;



    } 


    public static String purchaseItems(Warehouse w[])
    {

        Sring msg = "";

        String data[][] = {{ "Dallas", "1", "2"},
                   { "Arlington", "0", "5"},
                   { "Burleson", "3", "0"},
                   { "Keller", "10", "25"},
                   { "Dallas", "5", "0"},
                   { "Arlington", "0", "1"},
                   { "Burleson", "2", "4"},
                   { "Keller", "0", "30"},
                  };


        for( int i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
            for( int j=0; j<w.length; j++)
            {

                if (w[j].getAddress().getCity.equals(data[i][0]))   
                {

                 String msg += String.format("$%,.2f\n", (w[j].purchaseTelevision(Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]), 599.0) + w[j].purchaseComputer(Integer.parseInt(data[i][2]), 759.0)));

                }
            }

        }

        return msg;

    } 


    public static String printWarehouses(Warehouse w[])
    {
        String msg = "";

        for(int i=0; i<w.length;i++)

        {

            msg += String.format("%s\n", w[i].toString());

        }

        return msg;


    } 


    public static String printWarehouseCharge(Warehouse w[])
    {
        String msg = "";


        for(int i=0; i<w.length; i++)
        {

            msg += String.format("$%,.2f\n", w[i].calculateWarehouseCharge());

        }

        return msg;


    } 





} // end class WarehouseTest
```

Comment: What's the question? And use Lists instead of arrays.

Comment: dataArray does not appear to be defined

Comment: @MadPhysicist `String data[][] = {{ "Dallas", "1", "2"},...`

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code, not the least of which is a missing 2D array, Double doesn't have a ParseInt method, etc.  In general, it's helpful for you to post error messages where possible.  Workable code samples also help.

Comment: OK. Why are you creating and filling the wArray reference only to point it to another object immediately after? Also, data is declared inside another method. I refuse to believe that this is actual semi-working code. I do not think this code would compile.